# How can I deselect all rows in an UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I couldn't find this exact question, so I am posting it.

I was looking for a way to deselect all the rows or cells that are currently selected in a UITableView

Answer (score 8):

Simple one-liner: to deselect all rows, select `nil`! Like this

```
tableView.selectRow(at:nil...
```

(and fill out the rest of the call however you like, depending whether you want animation and scrolling).

Answer (score 7):

I found that the simpler solution is to extend UITableView

```
extension UITableView {
    func deselectAllRows(animated: Bool) {
        guard let selectedRows = indexPathsForSelectedRows else { return }
        for indexPath in selectedRows { deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: animated) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also do:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

inside of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this works..

```
extension UITableView {
    func deselectAllRows() {
        guard allowsSelection else { return }
    
        let multipleSelect = allowsMultipleSelection
    
        allowsSelection = false
    
        if multipleSelect {
            allowsMultipleSelection = true
        } else {
            allowsSelection = true   
        }
    }
}
```